# background image is not getting displayed

Tags: html, css

Am new to html. I went through similar questions but none solved my problem. Can anyone help. Thanks in advance.
The File location is correct.
My code:

```
<div id="bg">
</div>
```

Css:

```
#bg{
background-image: url("bg.png");
}
```

Comment: is the background image is in the same folder as the css and  called bg.png  ?

Comment: Where have you stored `bg.png`?  Check your path.

Comment: the Background is in the same folder as the html and css

Comment: @Billy yes its bg.png

Comment: specify width and height

Comment: set `width` and `height` or add content in the `div` you will see the `img` reason by default the `div` `width` and `height` is `0`

Comment: @siddharth make sure background image url path is correct

Answer (score 1):

***Try this:***

For demonstration i used 500px x 500px you can go with 100% x 100% too preferable with a container wrapped around the div. You don't need display: block; here in your css because a div already has display block as a standard for most browsers.

```
#bg{
   width:500px;  
   height:500px;
   background-image: url('bg.png');
}
```

Also be sure that the width and height matches the width and height of your image.

Your map with your files should be looking something like this:

```
index.html
bg.png
mycss.css
... many other .html / .php / .css
```

If you want to use a container, your css would look something like this. Try using container if you're going to work more with css, it's a really good thing too use for different browser sizes.

```
#bg{
   width: 100%;
   height: 100%;
}
.container{
   width: 500px;
   height: 500px;
}
```

And your HTML

```
<div class="container">
   <div id="bg"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: when i define the height and width as say 100px x 100px the full image is not being displayed.

Comment: even when i give width 100% and height : auto;

Comment: @siddharth Can you see a small part of the image?

Comment: @siddharth You have to set the same height and width for #bg or .container as the size of your image, then your image will be fully displayed on screen.

Comment: @VitorinoFernandes gave me the answer. Thanks for helping

Answer (score 0):

The path is wrong, check my comment under the question. The Image should be in the same place as the css or the path should be url('../bg.png'); if it is up one level etc.... try this and if it comes p red the path is wrong

```
#bg {
   background: #ff0000 url("bg.png") no-repeat right top;
  }
```

Comment: thanks Vitorino ,You're correct, I'm half asleep still.

Answer (score 0):

As you are setting the `background-image` of a div that div must contain something. And the `background-image` will sized accordingly with the size of the element contained inside the div.

Try this,

```
#bg{
    background: url("http://www.mascotdesign.com/_dev/images/famous-cartoon-character-mickey-mouse.png");
    background-size : 100% 100%;
    background-repeat : no-repeat;
}
```

[***jsFiddle***](http://jsfiddle.net/codeSpy/1f8fxvog/)

Comment: the complete img is not getting displayed.

Comment: I didn't add the contents inside div. That was my issue. Sorry my bad.
thanks for helping